# Laravel Query Multiple times on ViewServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I put my global variable using `view->with()` on **ViewServiceProvider.php** but the problem is it query multiple times on single page. is this a problem or it's really just this? it shows multiple times `select * from weather where id = 1` below

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, so the problem here is because you are using `*` for the view composer which means that you want to execute this code for every single view that is being rendered. A better approach is to include it to the partial that uses the `weather` instance, for example:

```
view()->composer('partial.nav', function($view) {}); // this will be used only on the navigation partial view.

// multiple views like this:

view()->composer(
    ['profile', 'dashboard'],
    function($view) {}
);

// or create a view composer class and register it as a singleton
$this->app->singleton(\App\Http\Composers\WeatherComposer::class);
```

Comment: does it need to follow the view folder structure? like `resources/views/components/nav.blade.php` then it will be `view()->composer('components.nav');`